# Using PowerShell to get OAuth2 Authorization Code for Google Sheets

Tags: powershell, redirect, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to automate the process of acquiring an `OAuth2` Authorization Code for use with Google Sheets.

I've created the Google Project and registered it with the redirect URI of `http://localhost/oauth2callback`

I've successfully gotten the Authorization Code manually by entering this URL into Chrome:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
  ?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth2callback
  &response_type=code
  &client_id=##CLIENTID##
  &scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fspreadsheets
  &access_type=offline
  &include_granted_scopes=true
  &state=state_parameter_passthrough_value
```

...and then extracting the Authorization Code by copying it out of the resulting URL shown in Chrome:

```
http://localhost/oauth2callback
  ?state=state_parameter_passthrough_value
  &code=##AUTHCODE##
  &scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets#
```

My attempts to replicate this process with PowerShell are failing miserably.  I think I'm missing some fundamental understanding of how all this HTTP redirect stuff works.

I've tried several variations on the theme, including taking the first redirect result and submitting it with another `Invoke-WebRequest` call, but no matter what I do, I only get a value back on the first call, and only if I set `-MaximumRedirection` to `0` -- and what I get back doesn't help me:

```
Function getAuthorizationCode($cliids) {
    $auturl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri=http`%3A`%2F`%2Flocalhost`%2Foauth2callback`&response_type=code`&client_id=$cliids`&scope=https`%3A`%2F`%2Fwww.googleapis.com`%2Fauth`%2Fspreadsheets`&access_type=offline`&include_granted_scopes=true`&state=state_parameter_passthrough_value";
    #$autrsp = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $auturl -UseDefaultCredentials -TimeoutSec 180 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
    $autrsp = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $auturl -UseDefaultCredentials -TimeoutSec 180 -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction Ignore;
    $autrdi = "";
    if ($autrsp.StatusCode -ge 300 -and $autrsp.StatusCode -lt 400) {
        $autrdi = $autrsp.Headers.Location;
    }   
    return $autrdi;
}
# Force main variables to be non-global
Function myMain($arglis) {
    $cliids = "##CLIENTID##";
    getAuthorizationCode $cliids;
}
# Force main variables to be non-global
myMain $Args;
```

This results in:

```
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin
  ?passive=1209600
  &continue=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
    ?redirect_uri%3Dhttp://localhost/oauth2callback
    %26response_type%3Dcode
    %26client_id%3D##CLIENTID##
    %26scope%3Dhttps://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
    %26access_type%3Doffline
    %26include_granted_scopes%3Dtrue
    %26state%3Dstate_parameter_passthrough_value
    %26from_login%3D1
    %26as%3D##LOGINCODE##
  &oauth=1
  &sarp=1
  &scc=1
```

Nothing in that resulting redirect value is the Authorization Code, and none of my efforts to use the information returned has gotten me an Authorization Code, either.

I've pored over a bunch of Google and StackOverflow search results and either I'm searching for the wrong things or not understanding what I'm finding.

I'm stumped.  Can someone help me figure out what direction I need to steer here?

Thanks!

Comment: With your powershell are you trying to open the browser for the user to authenticate or you want the authentication to be done in powershell as well? If you want to authenticate with username and password from powershell you have to use https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3

Comment: I am attempting to perform the task to fetch an Authorization code directly with Powershell, with no opening of browser.  Thank you for the link.  I need to read it more thoroughly, but at first glance it appears to cover the step of acquiring an Authentication Token, not the Authorization Code.  If so, it's not the step I'm on.

Comment: Also, even if this isn't the prescribed technique, the fact that the browser *can* produce the resulting URL without human intervention indicates that the information should be retrievable by a PowerShell script.  It's now something of an exciting opportunity to learn more about what happens behind the scenes with browsers and HTTP and redirects (oh my!).  Thus, attempting to replicate the behavior would not only be fun, but seriously educational for me.  So I'd really like to figure out how to perform this step in PowerShell.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use your browser, the browser will let you login to google and then authenticate you and send you authcode. If you want to automate the process using powershell or shell script use Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant where you send username and password as part of your request and the server returns the Auth code.But unfortunately it is not supported by google. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

So you have to dynamically open browser from your powershell and let users authenticate and once authenticated users should manually copy paste the Auth code in your console to generate access token. TO make it little easy you can redirect to a javascript page which opens a popup with the auth code. For example `redirect_uri=http://localhost:8899/getcode.html` will open `http://localhost:8899/getcode.html?code=xyz` If you write some javascript code inside `getcode.html` which reads code query parameter and displays to user in a pop up window it will be easy for users to copy it.

Another approach is custom redirect scheme. Here you have to install a custom scheme. This of it as another app(you can invoke a Shell or batch script) which is opened after athentication. You an write your own custom code to copy authcode to clipboard and read it inside powershell. (This can avoid manual copy paste). Refer this http://edoceo.com/howto/xfce-custom-uri-handler

Comment: Thank you again @Venkatesh Marepalli -- you are a veritable fount of information on the topic.  We still seem to be miscommunicating, though.

The step I'm on is not the Authentication step.  It's the Authorization step.  I do not have to log in to Google to accomplish this step manually.

I *do* have to log in to perform the Authentication step, but that is *not* the step I'm describing.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by Authorization step? getting authorization code? Let me know what you mean by this step and what happens at the end of this step so I will have a clear understanding

Comment: The original post shows the step in question, and the results.

After one has the Authorization Code, one can then use it to perform Authentication, and thus get an Access Token.  I'll post a more thorough example of the sequence from end to end in the morning.

Comment: You need to login to google to get Authorization code. You cannot get authorization code without logging in. This is a flow. Don't get confused by the OAuth terminology with the actual language.  You cannot get through any step without actually logging in i.e., username and password needs to be provided.

Comment: I'm basing the statement on the fact that I don't log in to Google as part of the operation.

I do need to check and see if maybe I'm implicitly logged in, and perhaps the human interactive login is being skipped?

Comment: That seems to be it.  Chrome has me signed into Google.  Whether I like it or not, apparently.

So for now I'll continue to do this step manually, and when I've got time to dig into the custom uri handler I'll do so -- that's where my best learning opportunity lives, I suspect.

Many thanks for all your help.